# How to release memory after clear a Groupbox in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, garbage-collection, dispose

I have a groupbox named "radGroupBox1" that I want to open a user control in that.
This is my code:

```
radGroupBox1.Controls.Clear();

_main2 = new Forms.MainControl2();
radGroupBox1.Controls.Add(_main2);
_main2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
_main2.Frm = this;
_main2.Show();
```

My problem is every time I execute this code , My memory increase. I check it in task manager. For example if you click 10 times on my button(run code) , Memory will increase 10 time. How can i release Memory allocated to previous object ?
Is there any way to Dispose it or force GC to release memory?

Comment: Are you closing (`_main2.Close()`) the form somewhere?

Comment: @OfirWinegarten Where should i do this?

Comment: hmm... i guess at the point where you want to close/hide the user control. Also why do you re-create it every time? why not just hide/show? it's not completely clear what you're doing

Comment: @OfirWinegarten because i want to show a completely new form of _main2. without last changes

Comment: @dama I use "Controls.Clear()" before adding items, Is that Clean all of my controls in radGroupBox1 or not?

Comment: You really should explain how you know the memory is increasing. Give us figures. And you should provide a [mcve] so we can see this behaviour ourselves.

Comment: @Enigmativity I wrote in question that I check Task manager

Comment: So, You are creating a new user control every time without closing the previous one. This might be the cause for the additional memory

Comment: @mosyflasher - Yes, I read the question. What did you see in Task Manager? What numbers? Please provide a [mcve] that lets us see it too.

Comment: @OfirWinegarten I think so, Is it common to create a public user control and use it entire program? I mean put "_main2 = new Forms.MainControl2();" in form load and never do it again?

Comment: As in most cases - it depends. As @Enigmativity already twice commented - without a complete example and description of the use-case we could never know. But at least make sure you are closing the form

Comment: @OfirWinegarten OK , How can i close form before new another?

Answer (score 3):

As you can read in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.clear(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Calling the Clear method does not remove control handles from memory. You must explicitly call the Dispose method to avoid memory leaks.

So this means that you have to `Dispose` the user control yourself. Also, be sure that inside the user-control you are disposing any disposable resources.

```
radGroupBox1.Controls.Clear();
_main2?.Dispose();
_main2 = new Forms.MainControl2();
radGroupBox1.Controls.Add(_main2);
_main2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
_main2.Frm = this;
_main2.Show();
```